# Recursive method to find the minimum number in a list of numbers

Tags: python, recursion

Given this sample list:

```
[5, 3, 9, 10, 8, 2, 7]
```

How to find the minimum number using recursion? The answer is `2`.

I found this in a question paper while I was doing recursion exercises. I can't figure out a way to solve this. To find it, do I have to sort the list first and then there's nothing to do recursively. Can any one show me a path?

Comment: If there's only one element in the list, the min is that element. Otherwise, compare the first elem with the min of the rest of the list. Good luck!

Comment: @georg Thanks for the tip sir! How can I start the recursion? Take the first element?

Comment: Do you want a general algorithm or for a specific language? I think the approach will vary a lot considering the available/allowed tools, such as sorting.

Comment: You can use an recursive algorithm to sort the list and with a single loop, find the minimum element.

Comment: @Molx Yes, I'm using python!

Comment: @Blogger: yes, take the first elem and look if there's more. If yes, recurse, if no, return the first elem.

Comment: @afk Yes sir that would be a better suggestion. But isn't there a direct recursive method to get the minimum without sorting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a recursive implementation of `min`:

```
l=[5, 3, 9, 10, 8, 2, 7]
def find_min(l,current_minimum = None):
    if not l:
        return current_minimum
    candidate=l.pop()
    if current_minimum==None or candidate<current_minimum:
        return find_min(l,candidate)
    return find_min(l,current_minimum)
print find_min(l)
>>>
2
```

Take into account that this should not be used in real programs and should be treated as an exercise. The performance will be worse than the built-in `min`by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: This is the one I'm looking for! A recursive method other than using built-ins! It's like the selection sort!

Comment: I guess the reason why you get better timings for the recursive version is that it destroys the list and hence actually runs only once ;)

Comment: To make this better, you can copy the list once and use a helper function (which will actually be your current implementation) to recurse by popping elements off the end of the copy. Then the original list will never be destroyed no matter what, and since you'll only be making one copy of the original list, you won't lose much in the way of performance.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import random
>>> arr=[random.randint(0,8) for r in xrange(10)]
>>> arr
[8, 2, 5, 1, 2, 4, 0, 3, 1, 1]
>>> def func(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr[0]
    else:
        return min(arr[0],func(arr[1:]))


>>> f(arr)
0
```

**NB** the recursion isn't really needed here.

Comment: Thank you @0x90! This makes sense. I was wondering when solving this, there's no other way other than using min() method right? :/ (I mean we can directly use min() to the list without going through recursion)

Comment: My answer shows a recursive implementation without calling `min`

Comment: @Blogger Simply replace `min(..)` with `if a[0] < ..; return a[0]; else ..` – I'll let you fill in the blanks.

Comment: Yea @deceze thanks for turning me to the correct track! :) I'll try it and get back with my code!

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses an accumulator to store the min value throughout the recursions.

```
list = [5, 3, 9, 10, 8, 2, 7]

def min_list(list, min=None):
    if len(list) < 1:
        return min
    return min_list(list[1:], list[0] if min is None or list[0] < min else min)

print(min_list(list))
```

Comment: Yep just like in selection sort! :D Thanks for the support @James

Answer (score 1):

Thats also working, but only for lists with a length that is a power of two. For other lengths you just have to tweak the split into smaller arrays. The approach is taken from [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

```
def findCloseToZero(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[0]
    else:
        first = findCloseToZero(l[0:int(len(l)/2)])
        sec = findCloseToZero(l[int(len(l)/2):])

        return first if abs(first) < abs(sec) else sec
```

Answer (score 1):

def find_smallest_elem(lst):

```
k=1

while k != len(lst):

    if lst[0] > lst[k]:

        return(find_smallest_elem(lst[k:]))
    else:

        k +=1

return(lst[0])
```

This seems to works fine

Answer (score 0):

this is my answer using recursion and a line of code

```
def min_value(n_list):
    return n_list[0] if len(n_list) == 1 else min(n_list[0], min_value(n_list[1:]))
```